# Selecting Multiple Dates in Calendar tvOS

Tags: swift, calendar, tvos

I managed to convert this iOS calendar component (https://github.com/lancy98/Calendar) to my tvOS application. Now I want to select more than one dates to show some report for selected dates. How can I do that ? Thanks

```html
class CalendarViewController: UIViewController, CalendarViewDelegate {
    


    
    @IBOutlet var placeholderView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // todays date.
        let date = NSDate()
        
        // create an instance of calendar view with
        // base date (Calendar shows 12 months range from current base date)
        // selected date (marked dated in the calendar)
        let calendarView = CalendarView.instance(date, selectedDate: date)
        calendarView.delegate = self
        calendarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        placeholderView.addSubview(calendarView)
        
        // Constraints for calendar view - Fill the parent view.
        placeholderView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[calendarView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["calendarView": calendarView]))
        placeholderView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[calendarView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["calendarView": calendarView]))
    }
    
    func didSelectDate(date: NSDate) {
        print("\(date.year)-\(date.month)-\(date.day)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not very specific as in what the actual problem you are facing is. So if my answer was not what you were looking for, please comment with more specifics and I'll try to help as much as I can.

I have not used this library before but I took a look at the code and the way I see it, there are 2 parts to this problem:

**1. Selecting multiple dates logically:** If that was the only issue, that part would have been simple as you get a callback to `didSelectDate` every time a date is selected. So technically you can set up an array  in your `CalendarViewController` and keep all the selected dates in there. That solution is not good though because you would be missing the visual representation and UX would be just terrible.

**2. Showing your selections visually on screen:** Unfortunately I don't see a way around this without modifying the code of the actual library to support multiple selections. Specifically a couple of classes: `MonthCollectionCell.swift` and `CalendarView.swift`. Mainly switching the `selectedDate` to be an array called `selectedDates` instead and supporting that throughout.

**EDIT:**

- So I was playing around with the code to try and explain it better and ended up adding the full feature to my fork: https://github.com/XemaCobra/Calendar
- To understand what was needed though, please check the commit and the changes that were made:
  https://github.com/XemaCobra/Calendar/commit/b9efa01f7ac5ae56bc0bdd72b3eeb1b618dbb00e
- The commented code in `ViewController.swift` should explain how to use it.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: hi Xemacobra, thanks for the reply. My app is a 7 min workout and includes this calendar , I want the user to select the days when does the workout. My question was not very specific because I'm a newbie in xcode and I didn't know exactly how to formulate that.

Comment: No problem. We are all always learning. I just wanted to know what the problem you're facing specifically so I can help. Do you know how to modify the code as I mentioned above or would you be interested in more explanation?

Comment: No , I don't know how to modify the code, I'm stuck there. (But also I don't want to abuse your help)

Comment: No worries, I'll do what I can. Are you looking to select a range of dates or multiple separate dates?

Comment: Multiple separate dates. This is my calendar http://i.imgur.com/NiAPF47.png were I want the user  to select the days when does the workout.

Comment: thank you , I changed the code but unfortunately, I don't know what I'm doing wrong and doesn't select multiple dates on calendar (I emailed you a copy of my project , to take a look )

Comment: Adding this here to help others if needed. The problem Mircea is having now is mostly related to the hardness of switching between 2 levels of focus  specially with a structure that has a collection view of collection views. The solution here would be to switch to the deeper level of focus (days) after a specific higher level of focus is selected (months).